# Блокирующий элемент очереди

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency

Есть таблица **sites**
Есть таблица URL - **urls**

url обрабатываются неким образом: с определенной периодичностью ставятся задачи с желаемым временем выполнения (`desired_time`) для каждого url и с помощью `ScheduledThreadPool` выполняются.
Поток (назовем его **A**), в бесконечном цикле проверяет активные url (с флагом `url.active == 1` в БД) и если нужно - ставит новую задачу, которая будет обработана другим потоком (назовем такие потоки **B**); или закрывает открытую задачу, так как ее не успел забрать ни один поток **B** и желаемое время **desired_time** ее выполнения истекло.

Поставленные задачи ждут своего выполнения (когда их заберет один из выполняющих потоков **B**) в `BlockingQueue`.

Возможна такая ситуация, когда **B** обработал задачу в тот момент, когда `desired_time` задачи вот-вот бы истекло. Пока поток **B** будет предпринимать действия по подготовке к передаче результата на сохранение в БД (или некую пост обработку) - `desired_time` окончательно истечет. Но задача уже выполнена и не может считаться просроченной. Однако, поток **A** в этот момент может как раз проверять задачу в БД и увидеть, что ее `desired_time` истек. Но так как результат еще не записан в БД - статус **фактически выполненной задачи** еще не изменен на *DONE* и **A** может закрыть задачу со статусом *ADDLED* (протух), после чего **B** завершит пост обработку и результат задачи будет сохранен в БД. В базе появится **выполненная задача с корректным результатом, но со статусом *ADDLED***.

Есть поток **С**, который выполняет роль некоего колбека для **B**. Если при обработке задачи в **B** возникла ошибка, не позволяющая продолжить обработку задачи, **B** передает задачу **C**. что бы она была закрыта со статусом *ERROR*. И того, мы имеем три не синхронизированных потока.

Понятно, что надо блокировать задачу для других потоков, когда:

- **B** получил результат и начал пост обработку до момента сохранения результата в БД
- **С** сохраняет задачу со статусом ERROR

Мониторов должно быть ровно столько, сколько URL обрабатывается. Т.е. один монитор на все задачи одного URL.

Как можно реализовать такие блокировки?

Comment: может проще снять с A закрытие задач, добавить поле "время завершения" и уже при просмотре разбираться, успела задача вовремя, или нет? Тогда A либо ставит задачу в очередь, либо не ставит, B выполняет и записывает результат, либо не выполняет и отдает работу C, C записывает ERROR.

Comment: Как вариант. Но это не блокировка, в этом случае теоретически возможны коллизии

Comment: Почему бы не добавить задаче в БД флаг "обрабатывается". Поток берет задачу, потом делает запрос `UPDATE task SET task.locked=1 WHERE task.id=:id AND task.locked=0` после чего смотрит, сколько строк обновил запрос. если 0 - значит, кто-то уже забрал задачу, забиваем, если 1 - успех, задачу никто не тронет, пока мы её обрабатываем. Только надо следить, чтобы не было "зависших" задач.

Comment: А почему бы вместе с результатом задачи не обновлять и статус? Тогда *ADDLED* будет заменен на условный *COMPLETED*, и вы получите eventually consisted данные.

Answer (score 5):

Я обычно использую кэш, в котором держу объекты для синхронизации.

```
Ehcache idLockingCache = ..... ;
private Lock idLockingCacheLock = new ReentrantLock();

public Object getLock(String key) {
    Element element = idLockingCache.get(key);
    if (element == null) {
        idLockingCacheLock.lock();
        try {
            element = idLockingCache.get(key);
            if (element == null) {
                element = new Element(key, new Object());
                idLockingCache.put(element);
            }
        } finally {
            idLockingCacheLock.unlock();
        }
    }
    return element.getObjectValue();
}
```

Использование

```
//key в вашем случае это либо id url-а из БД, либо сам URL
Object lock = getLock(key); 
synchronized (lock) {
    //work
}
```

И соответственно синхронизируете во всех местах.

P.S. Для распределенных блокировок использую Hazelcast IMap.lock(key)/unlock(key)

Answer (score 0):

Я не понимаю, зачем здесь вообще нужны какие то блокировки. Нужно завести дополнительную структуру данных `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<String,Status>`. Ключем будем выступать `url`, а значением статус задачи, которая обрабатывает данный `url`. Теперь в момент, когда поток `A` забирает задачу, он выставляет ей статус `PROCESSED` и больше ее не трогает, передавая потоку `B`. Поток `B` занимается обработкой, после того, как задача завершилась, он просто сохраняет полученный результат в базу данных и удаляет задачу из `map`. Если произошла ошибка, аналогичным образом поступает поток `C`.

Если хотите жестко регламентировать задачи по времени, т.е. не сохранять результат, если задача не выполнилась в уставленное время, есть следующий вариант. Вместо статуса хранить ссылку на поток `Worker`, занимающийся обработкой. Теперь когда поток `B` попытается сохранить результат он должен сделать проверку и если поток не прерван то сохраняем результат.

Код примерно такой будет:

```
 private static class Worker extends Thread {
    private final AtomicBoolean isAddled = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private void saveToDatabase(Result result) {
        if (!isAddled.get()) {
            //логика сохранения
        }

        workers.remove(result.url);
    }
}
```

а в потоке `A` делать следующую проверку:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
private static class Task {
    private final int desired_time ;
    private final String url ;
}

private static boolean isReadyForProcessing(Task task) {
    Worker updatedWorker = workers.computeIfPresent(task.url, (url, worker) -> {
        worker.isAddled.set(System.currentTimeMillis() > task.desired_time);
        return worker;
    });

    return updatedWorker == null;
}
```

Получилось немного сумбурно и запутанно, но надеюсь суть ясна.